# field with multiple foreign keys

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

I have researched this on my own but not really sure of the terms I should use and have not gotten far.  Basically I'm trying to figure out how to implements tags for a table row.  So if my table was musicFile, my tags would be artist, genre, etc....  But lets say some musicFiles would only have artist, or genre so its variable.

I think I would need a separate table for Tags but even then there would have to be foreign keys that are placed in the musicFile table and I end up at the starting point since its 1-1, meaning that its still variable.  I would not know at database creation time how many fields to dedicate to Tag foreign keys.

Comment: think this is my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7094232/530933

Comment: hi owen, are you looking for a way to implement `Tags` in your system or you are asking about `multiple foreign keys` in general, because there are many ways of `Tag` implementations, there is  1 to 1 or 1 to many or even denormalized in a single table, it all depends on which way you want that fits you.

Comment: i am looking for the proper table format for 1->many, right?  one music file to many tag fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `MusicFile` has multiple `Artists` and an `Artist` has multiple `MusicFiles` then yes you need a link table between the two (as per the answer in your comment). However, if, for example, you only ever want to attach a single `Genre` to any given `MusicFile`, then you could just have a field for genre inside the `MusicFile` table.